How to create bar models and annotate them?
Hi I am trying to do something like the following.

Honestly, I only know how to create the bar itself using tikz. Otherwise I am not sure otherwise.
THank you

For the braces: see the decorations library in Tikz. For the labels see nodes, with options anchors, rounded corners and minimum widrth. Feel free to add code, which illustrates your problem.

As supplement to nice @MS-SPO answer (actually short essay how to use tikz package in your case) (+1), where for braces are used calligraphy library and for shapes positions library positioning.
MWE for this a bit less elementary solution is:
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,
                calligraphy,% had to be after decorations.pathreplacing
                positioning
                }

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 2mm and 0 mm,
   bar/.style args = {#1/#2}{draw, fill=#1, minimum width=#2mm,
                            anchor=north west, inner sep=0, minimum height=8mm,
                            node contents={}},
    BC/.style = {decorate,
                 decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=6pt,
                             pre =moveto, pre  length=1pt,
                             post=moveto, post length=1pt,
                             raise=1mm,
                             #1},% for mirroring of brace
                 thick,
                 pen colour=black},
 blubb/.style = {draw=gray, rounded corners,
                 minimum width=12mm, minimum height=5mm, node contents={}},
                        ]
%   2 bars  
\node (A) [bar=gray!30/61.3];      
\node (B) [bar=orange!30/48.0, below right=of A.south west];
    
%   dashed line 
\draw[dashed]   (B.south -| A.east)  coordinate(C) -- 
                     (A.south east);
%   braces  
\draw[BC] (A.north west) -- node[above=3mm] {613}   (A.north east);
\draw[BC] (B.south east) -- node[below=3mm] {480}   (B.south west);
\draw[BC] (C) -- node[below=3mm] {?}                (B.south east);
%
\draw[BC] (A.north east) -- (C) node [midway, right=5mm, blubb,
                                      label=right:units];
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Addendum:
Considered your comment, bar title can be simple add as labels to bars:
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing,
                calligraphy,% had to be after decorations.pathreplacing
                positioning
                }

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 2mm and 0 mm,
   bar/.style args = {#1/#2}{draw, fill=#1, minimum width=#2mm,
                            anchor=north west, inner sep=0, minimum height=8mm,
                            node contents={}},
    BC/.style = {decorate,
                 decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=6pt,
                             pre =moveto, pre  length=1pt,
                             post=moveto, post length=1pt,
                             raise=1mm,
                             #1},% for mirroring of brace
                 thick,
                 pen colour=black},
 blubb/.style = {draw=gray, rounded corners,
                 minimum width=12mm, minimum height=5mm, node contents={}},
                        ]
%   2 bars  
\node (A) [bar=gray!30/61.3,
           label=left: ticked sold];    % <---    
\node (B) [bar=orange!30/48.0, 
           label=left: bar title,       % <---
           below right=of A.south west];
    
%   dashed line 
\draw[dashed]   (B.south -| A.east)  coordinate(C) -- 
                     (A.south east);
%   braces  
\draw[BC] (A.north west) -- node[above=3mm] {613}   (A.north east);
\draw[BC] (B.south east) -- node[below=3mm] {480}   (B.south west);
\draw[BC] (C) -- node[below=3mm] {?}                (B.south east);
%
\draw[BC] (A.north east) -- (C) node [midway, right=5mm, blubb,
                                      label=right:units];
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Thank you so much. It is a lot of detail. I can actually do the rest using this example! I should have probably uploaded one image. They were just examples.

@user292225, ok. after than consider to accept one of answer which you find the most helpful .

This is probably a basic question. I am trying to add a title to the left of each bar. So I did it like this. \draw (-2.5,-1.3) node[anchor=west] {Tickets Sold}; Is there a better way to do it so that both titles are aligned and in the middle of the bar.

@user292225, simpler is write it as label. See edited answer.

This example demonstrates to you all you need to draw the bars you showed. It's one way to do it. E.g. some steps you could write more compact, but will probably harder to read to to adapt for Tikz-novices.

Bars
The easiest way is to perceive them as nodes with empty text, where you draw its shape, which is rectangular by default, and add some fill color. So its options consist of:

bar, which is a style used for all bars (see below)
a fill-color
a minimum width, which represents the bars length

    \node[bar,fill=yellow!10,minimum width=6.13cm]  (A) at (0,0) {};      

Self defined styles
Let's have a look at style bar first:

it draws its outer shape in the default color (black)
it anchors it to its lower left corner (south west) which makes positioning more controllable: that's where the nodes coordinate is
inner sep=0, minimum height=1cm define one dimension of the bar

    bar/.style={draw,anchor=south west,inner sep=0,minimum height=1cm},

The blubb style used later for the empty fields:

drawn, with rounded corners
at a given width and height

    blubb/.style={draw,rounded corners,
                  minimum width=12mm,anchor=west,minimum height=5mm},

Putting a dashed line of the correct length
After placing two bars (A) and (B) in absolute coordinates there is the task to draw a line.
Its starting point is simple: lower right corner of (A), i.e. (A.south east).
The end point shall be the intersection of a line, starting horizontally at lower right of B (B.south east and a vertical coming from A's lower right A.south east; we also would like to remember this intersection point as (C) :
    % ~~~ dashed line ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw[dashed]   (A.south east) -- 
                    (B.south east -| A.south east) coordinate(C);

Braces
Basic Tikz-idea:

draw a line between two points
decorate it with a brace, i.e. replace the straight line by a more complicated path

So simplified we turn, assuming (K) and (L) were defined before
\draw (K) -- (L);

into
\draw[decorate] (K) -- (L);

To do that, you need to have:
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
...
    decoration=brace,   % in the style-section
...
    % ~~~ braces ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw[decorate] ([yshift=2mm]A.north west) -- node[anchor=south]  {613}
                    ([yshift=2mm]A.north east);

The two points shouldn't be a problem to understand. Their starting points are shifted upwards a bit for better visibility. You can put text as an extra node as shown, where you anchor it as needed (south here).
To have the middle of the brace at the correct side/direction, you sometimes have to draw from left to right or vice versa.
For the blubb one way to do it is like this:

put a node with blubb style AND give it a name, e.g. (X)
put a label, to rhe right side of X

    \draw[decorate] ([xshift=2mm]A.north east) -- 
                    node[blubb,xshift=2mm] (X) {}   % remember this one
                    ([xshift=2mm]C);
    \node[anchor=west] at (X.east) {unit};          % put some text after X


\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    bar/.style={draw,anchor=south west,inner sep=0,minimum height=1cm},
    decoration=brace,
    blubb/.style={draw,rounded corners,
                  minimum width=12mm,anchor=west,minimum height=5mm},
 ]
    % ~~~ 2 bars ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \node[bar,fill=yellow!10,minimum width=6.13cm]  (A) at (0,0) {};      
    \node[bar,fill=orange!10,minimum width=4.80cm]  (B) at (0,-1.3) {};
    
    % ~~~ dashed line ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw[dashed]   (A.south east) -- 
                    (B.south east -| A.south east) coordinate(C);
    
    % ~~~ braces ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw[decorate] ([yshift=2mm]A.north west) -- node[anchor=south]  {613}
                    ([yshift=2mm]A.north east);

    \draw[decorate] ([yshift=-2mm]B.south east) -- node[anchor=north] {480}
                    ([yshift=-2mm]B.south west);

    \draw[decorate] ([yshift=-2mm]C) -- node[anchor=north] {?}
                    ([yshift=-2mm]B.south east) ;
                    
    \draw[decorate] ([xshift=2mm]A.north east) -- 
                    node[blubb,xshift=2mm] (X) {}   % remember this one
                    ([xshift=2mm]C);
    \node[anchor=west] at (X.east) {unit};          % put some text after X

 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

